# Reach @ jumping from one building to another

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, projectile, free-fall

Let's assume I'm in the rooftop of a building (Building A) and want to jump to the rooftop of another building (Building B). Forget about injuries... is just hypothetical.

Building A has a height of 30 meters (90 feet)... and Building B has a height of 10 meters (30 feet). Just round the height difference to 60 feet or 20 meters.

From a standing position at the border of Building A (no running impulse), and with the strength of a normal man (1.75 mts tall, 70 kg)... how far is the MAXIMUM gap I can reach?

Comment: How 'strong' is a normal man? ;-) Or is it an Olympian?

Comment: Mmmm how far can you jump from standing (just impulsed by your legs)? Lets say 2 meters... does that sound logical?

Comment: You tell me Juan, you tell me. What I'm getting at is that this problem is poorly defined. There's no 'standard human'. Better would be to calculate initial speed and angle to make the jump successful.

Comment: That's not what I've asked... it's poorly defined because that's the way it came up... just a bunch of friends arguing about if it is or it isn't possible to jump a gap of 12 meters. If you're going to get so precise, so this question is not for you.

Comment: As the question stands it's basically unanswerable.

Comment: If you still wanna answer... jumping in the ground, you reach 2 mts with a max heigth of 50 cms (0.5 mts)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajectory_of_a_projectile#Angle_required_to_hit_coordinate_.28x.2Cy.29 I;m not providing an answer because this question will get voted to close. Best of luck, though.

Comment: If you only harass people with annoying comments so you'll get questions to be closed... it's pretty simple to solve... just I don't wanna go and check all the formulas to get an answer that someone here could do with its eyes closed. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I won't vote to close it. But others probably will. There's no conceptual physics in the question. And this site rarely provides full answers if the OP shows no work of his own. It's not personal. No one could do this with their eyes closed: it's not that simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from the equation in @Gert's [wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajectory_of_a_projectile#Angle_required_to_hit_coordinate_.28x.2Cy.29) in the comments under your quetions:
$$\tan\theta = \frac{v^2 \pm \sqrt{v^4 - g(gx^2+2yv^2)}}{gx}.$$
This equation gives the angle of launch in order to reach the coordinate $(x,y)$ starting from $(0,0)$ with initial velocity $v$ with gravitational acceleration $g$. In our case, $y = -20$ meters and $g = 9.8$ m/s$^2$. We don't care about $\theta$, and we want to know the maximum $x$ that can be reached. We'll figure out what $v$ is later.

In order for that equation to have any answer, the part under the square root must not be negative. So,
$$v^4 - g(gx^2+2yv^2) \geq 0$$
$$gx^2+2yv^2 \leq \frac{v^4}{g}$$
$$x^2 \leq \frac{v^4}{g} - 2yv^2$$
Taking only the positive answer:
$$x \leq \sqrt{\frac{v^4}{g^2} - \frac{2yv^2}{g}}$$
$$x \leq \frac{v}{g}\sqrt{v^2 - 2yg}$$
This represents the maximum horizontal distance.

Now, to figure out $v$, I'm going to use [the vertical leap of some NBA basketball players](http://theexercisers.com/how-to-increase-vertical-jump/average-vertical-jump/highest-vertical-jump-in-nba/):  45 inches or 115 cm. The starting velocity needed to reach a height is
$$\frac{1}{2}mv^2 = mgh$$
$$v = \sqrt{2gh}$$
Substituting in $h = 1.15$ meters gives $v = 4.75$ m/s.
Solving for $x$ in the above equation gives
$$x \leq \frac{4.75}{9.8}\sqrt{4.75^2 - 2(-20)(9.8)} = 9.86\,m$$

Incidentally, the launch angle is 13 degrees above horizontal to reach that distance.

Comment: Great answer... but the average vertical leap in NBA is 0.71 mts. http://www.topendsports.com/testing/results/vertical-jump.htm

Anyway, great!

Comment: I went for the top leaps to get maximum distance. Anyway, I'm more amused by the 13 degree launch angle. You basically have to fall off the roof and push off the vertical wall to make it across.

Comment: Yes... but your top leap breaks my argument that for an average man it was pretty impossible to achieve hahaha

But as I said, your answer (or the way you got there) is what I needed. I'm still trying to do some calculations but I'm all rusted!

Comment: I have chosen your answer as the right one because even if it's not with the data assumed in my post, the way, the method you get to the result, is just what I was looking for.
I wanna thank to everyone for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

Using the information provided by the OP, in the comments:

> [...] jumping in the ground, you reach 2 mts with a max heigth of 50 cms (0.5 mts)

Using that information we can construct a parabola of the trajectory (figure not to scale):

[image: Parabolic trajectory.]

Its mathematical function is:

$$y=ax^2+bx+c,$$

and with three points supplied, $(0,0)(1,0.5)(2,0)$, we find:

$$y=x-\frac{1}{2}x^2$$

Since as the rooftop of B is $20\:\mathrm{m}$ lower than that of A, let's find the value of $x$ for $y=-20$:

$$-20=x-\frac{1}{2}x^2,$$

$$x-\frac{1}{2}x^2+20=0.$$

Which is a standard quadratic equation with a positive root for:

$$\large{x=7.344\:\mathrm{m}}.$$

This is the approx. maximum distance between the buildings for the jumper not to plummet to serious injury or death.

Comment: Really neat and simple answer... thank you! I'll do some maths in my own and check all of your formulas... and I'll select the correct answer as my heart states it(?)

Answer (score 0):

Giving the average standing long jump to be between 2.2 and 2.3 meters ([Source](http://www.topendsports.com/testing/tests/longjump.htm)) length and 20 meters doesn't give you all that long to fall to keep that forward momentum I'd estimate the building could be maybe 3-4 meters away max for you to splat onto Building B.. Unless you left out the fact that you were hiding a glider under your shirt...